# Homomorphism from Infinite Graph to finite Graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How to prove that if there is a homomorphism from every subgraph G' of infinite graph G to a finite and fixed graph H there is also a homomorphism from G to H?

Comment: I think you are missing some conditions. Otherwise, since $G$ is a subgraph of itself the conclusion is true instantly.

Comment: is an infinte graph also a sub-graph of itself?

Comment: Of course, it's just true for every graph

Comment: every graph is a subgraph of itself

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments, this is trivial as stated, since $G$ is a subgraph of itself. You probably meant to ask how to prove the following statement:

> If there is a homomorphism from every **finite** subgraph of a graph $G$ to a certain finite graph $H$, then there is also a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$.

This is a generalization of the [De Bruijn–Erdős theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_theorem_(graph_theory)) which is the case $H=K_n$. Any of the usual proofs of the De Bruijn–Erdős theorem can easily be adapted to prove the more general statement. Here is a proof using the [Tychonoff product theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem).

Consider $V(H)$ as a topological space with the discrete topology; then the product space
$$X=\prod_{v\in V(G)}V(H)$$
is compact by Tychonoff's theorem. For each edge $e=uv\in E(G)$ define
$$F_e=\{f\in X:f(u)f(v)\in E(H)\}.$$
It follows from the definition of the product topology and the fact that $H$ is finite that each $F_e$ is a closed set in $X$. Moreover, from the fact that every finite subgraph of $G$ admits a homomorphism to $H$, it follows that $\{F_e:e\in E(G)\}$ has the finite intersection property. Since $X$ is compact, it follows that the intersection
$$F=\bigcap_{e\in E(G)}F_e$$
is nonempty. Plainly any element of $F$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$.